# Query to only show column names with value

Tags: php, sql, database, fetch

I'm working on a filtering system which will only show the results matching a certain criteria.

The user makes their 'filter' which adds that preference to a filters table. The column names is the condition.

I want to show a table where the table head columns are showing only the columns that match the condition 'on' and when off is empty.

```
function get_filter_columns($filter_id) {

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM filters WHERE id="$filter_id"') or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<thead>
          <tr>';

         // echo mysql_fetch_array($result);

         echo count($result, COUNT_RECURSIVE); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        $counter++;

        echo '<th>'.$row['total'].'</th>';

        echo mysql_field_name($result, $counter);

    }

    echo '</tr>
          </thead>';        

}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @barbashov How can I list all of the column names from a table that only has the string "on"

Comment: you mean column names containing string "on"?

Answer (score 1):

Change line

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM filters WHERE id="$filter_id"') or die(mysql_error());
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filters WHERE id='".$filter_id."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: $filter_id doesn't need to be independent here. I'm looking to only display the column names with value.